# getsockopt: connection timed out

Tags: postgresql, sockets, go, connection-timeout, go-iris

I rewrite my project from python tornado to go(use iris framework). The basic function tested ok. When I test under high concurrence.the app always stops a while and then comes out the errors:

```
(dial tcp 192.168.1.229:6543: getsockopt: connection timed out)
```

the 6543 port is the postgresql port used with pgbouncer...the pgbouncer and postgresl process runs Ok.

Also, I find that the memcache connect time out sometimes(the memcache process is still working).

Does this happen because too many connections? Or some connections not 
closed on time?
How can I avoid this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Check your [PgBouncer config](https://pgbouncer.github.io/config.html). Try to increase `max_client_conn` option. Then experiment with concurrency level and requests count during stress test. Another possible issue can be that you don't return connections to pool.

Comment: It is helplessness that increase the  max_client_conn in pgbouncer.ini.The memcache also reported that connect timeout

Comment: Try to do next thing: run 2 copies of your application and stress test only one of them. After it will start throwing errors, start to work with second copy of application. In this way you'll know, if it's problem of your application (2nd copy runs well), or you reach some OS or PgBouncer/Memcached limitations (2nd copy fails quickly).